# Sizzle JS how does it work?

Tags: javascript, sizzle

I was looking into the sizzle.js source code for a school project, and I noticed something strange. At the bottom of the code there is this line of code saying:

```
window.Sizzle = Sizzle;
```

But i can't find anything in the code saying anything about a:

```
var Sizzle = .....
```

The only thing i find that would resemble the Sizzle variable would be:

```
function Sizzle( selector, context, results, seed ) {
```

Now for my question. Is it possible for a function to act as an object like this? Or is it something that I've missed?

Comment: Functions are objects. Function declarations create variables in the scope of the declaration, so a global function declaration creates a global variable. Also, function and variable declarations are processed before any code is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a function is itself a Javascript object and can be assigned to some other variable.